# Sort a sentence in Java without using an Array

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I want to be able to sort a sentence sample input `Python:PHP:C++:C:Java:HTML`

without using an array or array methods to sort the sentence.

Output should be something like this;

```
Top programming languages in alphabetical order:
1. C
2. C++
3. HTML
4. Java
5. PHP
6. Python
```

Here is what I got started with but am stuck and can't find anything on the internet that doesn't use Array.

```
import java.util.*;

public class SortProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Declare Variables
        String topLang = "";
        int separator = 0;
        String holder = "";
        String top = "";

        // Create a Scanner object attached to the keyboard
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        // input
        System.out.print("Enter a list of the top programming languages: ");
        topLang = input.next();

        // separate each word
        while (topLang.length() > 0) {
            separator = topLang.indexOf(":");
            holder = topLang.substring(0, separator);
            topLang = topLang.substring(separator, topLang.length());
            
        }

        System.out.println("  Position Language");
        System.out.println("==========================");
    }

}
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use an array? ``String[] words = topLang.split(":");``

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to use the Java 8 Stream API:

```java
String topLang = "Python:PHP:C++:C:Java:HTML";

Pattern.compile(":").splitAsStream(topLang).sorted().forEach(System.out::println);
```

*Output*

```
C
C++
HTML
Java
PHP
Python
```

---

The alternative, staying close to the implementation in the question, is to use a `List`. If you don't want arrays at all, use a non-array list implementation like `LinkedList`.

```java
String topLang = "Python:PHP:C++:C:Java:HTML";

List<String> result = new LinkedList<>();
int start = 0;
for (int end; (end = topLang.indexOf(':', start)) != -1; start = end + 1)
    result.add(topLang.substring(start, end));
result.add(topLang.substring(start));
Collections.sort(result);
for (String s : result)
    System.out.println(s);
```

Same output as above.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an another solution that uses a PriorityQueue and regex.

```
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    Queue<String> sortedLanguages = new PriorityQueue<>();
    System.out.print("Enter a list of the top programming languages: ");
    String input = scanner.next();
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("[^:]+").matcher(input);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        sortedLanguages.add(matcher.group());
    }
    System.out.print("Top programming languages in alphabetical order:");
    for (int i = 1, size = sortedLanguages.size(); i <= size; i++) {
        System.out.printf("\n%d. %s", i, sortedLanguages.poll());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `TreeSet` data structure to store the sorted strings:

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class SortProgram {

    // Python:PHP:C++:C:Java:HTML
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Declare Variables
        String topLang = "";
        int separator = 0;
        String holder = "";
        String top = "";

        // Create a Scanner object attached to the keyboard
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        // input
        System.out.print("Enter a list of the top programming languages: ");
        topLang = input.next();

        // separate each word
        Set<String> languages = new TreeSet<>();
        while (topLang.length() > 0) {
            separator = topLang.indexOf(":");

            if (separator == -1) {
                separator = topLang.length() - 1;
            }

            holder = topLang.substring(0, separator);
            topLang = topLang.substring(separator + 1);
            languages.add(holder);
        }

        AtomicInteger position = new AtomicInteger(1);
        System.out.println("  Position Language");
        System.out.println("==========================");
        languages.forEach(language -> System.out.println(position.getAndIncrement() + ": " + language));
    }

}
```

o maybe if you don't want to use any data structure at all you could build a sort algorithm like bubble sort by just using strings.